# How to use NLsolve to solve "only 1D equation"

Tags: julia

The following is ok,

```
function f!(F,x)
    F[1]=x[1]^3+8
    F[2]=x[2]^2 -8
end

nlsolve(f!, [1.,2])
```

however, the following is bad:

```
function f!(F,x)
    F[1]=x[1]^3+8
end

nlsolve(f!, [1.])
```

Comment: Can you please specify what's "bad"? Like, post the actual error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with 1D. The problem is with Jacobian of your function.

Here is an example of the same in 2D:

```
    julia> function f!(F,x)
               F[1]=x[1]^3+8
               F[2]=x[2]^3-2
           end
    f! (generic function with 1 method)

    julia> nlsolve(f!, [0.,0.])
    Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
     * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
     * Starting Point: [0.0, 0.0]
     * Zero: [NaN, NaN]
     * Inf-norm of residuals: 8.000000
     * Iterations: 1000
     * Convergence: false
       * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
       * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: false
     * Function Calls (f): 1001
     * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 2
```

Now let us go back to your function. If you start from `[1.0]` you are unlucky and `nlsolve` in the root finding process hits `[0.0]` exactly with its default parameters and you have a problem that then Jacobian is `[0.0]`.

You can see it by running:

```
julia> function f!(F,x)
           F[1]=x[1]^3+8
       end
f! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> nlsolve(f!, [1.], show_trace=true, extended_trace=true, iterations=3);
Iter     f(x) inf-norm    Step 2-norm
------   --------------   --------------
     0     9.000000e+00              NaN
 * f(x): [9.0]
 * g(x): [3.0]
 * x: [1.0]
 * delta: NaN
 * rho: NaN
     1     8.000000e+00     1.000000e+00
 * f(x): [8.0]
 * g(x): [0.0]
 * x: [0.0]
 * delta: 2.9999999999239875
 * rho: 0.3777777777854353
     2              NaN              NaN
 * f(x): [NaN]
 * g(x): [0.0]
 * x: [NaN]
 * delta: 2.9999999999239875
 * rho: NaN
     3              NaN              NaN
 * f(x): [NaN]
 * g(x): [0.0]
 * x: [NaN]
 * delta: 2.9999999999239875
 * rho: NaN
```

You can fix it by changing a starting point or by changing `factor`:

```
julia> nlsolve(f!, [10.])
Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
 * Starting Point: [10.0]
 * Zero: [-2.0]
 * Inf-norm of residuals: 0.000000
 * Iterations: 18
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
   * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
 * Function Calls (f): 17
 * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 11

julia> nlsolve(f!, [1.], factor=0.5)
Results of Nonlinear Solver Algorithm
 * Algorithm: Trust-region with dogleg and autoscaling
 * Starting Point: [1.0]
 * Zero: [-2.0]
 * Inf-norm of residuals: 0.000000
 * Iterations: 7
 * Convergence: true
   * |x - x'| < 0.0e+00: false
   * |f(x)| < 1.0e-08: true
 * Function Calls (f): 8
 * Jacobian Calls (df/dx): 8
```

Also - as Chris suggests - Roots.jl has methods that are more robust because you have derivative free methods in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, but Roots.jl is probably better suited for this kind of equation. Its methods are directly for 1-dimensional rootfinding problems and can be more robust.